# Extracting specific text from the body of a response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a request that is being sent as a POST method, when the request comes back I need to extract the order_id and run the next transaction using the extracted order_id. My implementation is currently just returning a value of "0" when it should be the 15 character order_id. How do I extract the string from Jmeter?

Response in the body:

> response_code=2 response_code_text=Missing required request field:
>   Order ID. time_stamp=1479849486545 retry_recommended=false
>   secondary_response_code=0 order_id=356005935614233
>   capture_reference_id=1 iso_code= bank_approval_code=
>   bank_transaction_id= batch_id= avs_code=
>   credit_card_verification_response= reference_id=1 bin=
>   retrieval_reference_number= payer_identifier= system_trace_number=
>   captured_amount=0.00 emv_data= bank_response_code=

[image: My Implementation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into "RegExp Tester" window of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and using your response exactly as it appears at the page I would recommend using the following Regular Expression:

```
order_id=(\d+)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression Extractor Demo]

Check out [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter [User Manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html) for entry level information on Regular Expressions.

Just in case your response is malformed, I would recommend using the same approach to test your Regular Expressions against real server response. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for details.

Comment: The expression statement works like a charm, my issue is that my script isn't assigning the value to the variable order_id.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I see from your screen shot and description, change the "field to check" option to body and try the following regular expression:

```
order_id=(.*) capture_reference_id
```

Comment: this solution didn't work for me, my order_id is still pulling back as 0